# How to <use> several animated instances of a defined object in SVG with different 'begin' points

Tags: javascript, svg

Let's say we have the following defined object 'A' in SVG:

```
<defs>
<g id="A">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red">
  <animate id="C" attributeName="cx" values="0;1;2;3;4;5" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.6;0.8;1" begin="click" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</circle>
</g>
</defs>
```

There are several instances of it (in fact tens):

```
<use id="B1" href="#A" x="0" y="0"/>
<use id="B2" href="#A" x="0" y="20"/>
```

Now I would like to start each animation at a different point, for example the 'begin' of B1 to be 0s, that of B2 to be 0.2s, etc.

Trying to use javascript to set the "begin" attribute using B1.setAttribute('begin'), or similar, won't work because 'begin' is an attribute of A's circle animation. Other attributes I tried to change are 'animation-delay' and 'animation-play-state'. I understand that I need to reference "#C" of each instance separately. Is this possible?

[The objects are actually molecules and I want them to behave randomly, not all in synchrony.]

Comment: Don't use <use>. just have multiple copies of the circle and animate them as you wish. Just because you have access to a spanner doesn't mean you should use it when you have two pieces of wood and some nails.

Comment: @Robert-Longson Your suggestion is to repeat the same code like forty times? That's against all computing principles.

Comment: Generate it with javascript then.

Comment: There's huge overhead under the hood with <use> elements, keeping them in sync. If you don't need/want that then it's better not to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are animating the position, why not animate the `x` and `y` attributes of the `<use>` element?

`<animate>` elements cannot be reused, you have to write them out seperately for each instance.

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -20 100 100" height="95vh">
  <defs>
    <g id="A">
       <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use id="B1" href="#A" x="0" y="0">
    <animate id="C" attributeName="x" values="0;1;2;3;4;5" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.6;0.8;1" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <use id="B2" href="#A" x="0" y="20">
    <animate id="C" attributeName="x" values="0;1;2;3;4;5" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.6;0.8;1" begin="0.2s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

`animation-delay` and `animation-play-state` are part of the CSS keyframes animation module, and have no bearing on SVG/SMIL animations. They also cannot be used as attributes, only as CSS properties.

You can use a CSS Keyframes animation to make the notation a bit more terse:

```css
.moving {
  animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

.moving#B1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.moving#B2 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    x: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    x: 1px;
  }
  40% {
    x: 2px;
  }
  60% {
    x: 3px;
  }
  80% {
    x: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    x: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -20 100 100" height="95vh">
  <defs>
    <g id="A">
       <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use class="moving" id="B1" href="#A" x="0" y="0"/>
  <use class="moving" id="B2" href="#A" x="0" y="20"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Neat. I might combine the two answers, by using javascript to put in the <use> tags and .moving styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to randomize element animations dynamically – you can as well generate both `<circle>` and `<animate>` elements via javaScript.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("svg");

let circles = [
  { cx: 10, cy: 10, r: 2.5, fill: "red" },
  { cx: 20, cy: 10, r: 2.5, fill: "green" },
  { cx: 30, cy: 10, r: 2.5, fill: "purple" },
  { cx: 40, cy: 10, r: 2.5, fill: "orange" }
];

addCirclesAnimated(svg, circles, 1, 3);

function addCirclesAnimated(svg, circles, min, max) {
  let circlesMarkup = "";
  circles.forEach((circle, i) => {
    let id = `circle${i}`;
    let randX = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    let randY = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    let randBegin = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    let randDuration = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    circlesMarkup += `<circle id="${id}" cx="${circle.cx}" cy="${circle.cy}" r="${circle.r}" fill="${circle.fill}" />
<animateTransform href="#${id}" attributeName="transform" type="translate"
 values="0,0; ${randX},${randY}; 0,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" begin="-${randBegin}s" dur="${randDuration}s" repeatCount="indefinite" />`;
  });
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", circlesMarkup);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
</svg>
```

The above example uses the svg SMIL animation element [`<animateTransform>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) to apply an animated transformations via translate.
This way, we don't need to calculate an explicit new `cx` and `cy` attribute value based on the current/previous value.

Comment: Great suggestion. It looks neater than a purely javascript-canvas implementation.

Comment: @Chrystomath: thanks, but quite likely a canvas approach would wipe the floor with animated svg when it comes to performance – especially if you need to animate e.g 10,000 molecules. Even though being kind of a  `<use>` fan. Robert Longson is right: `<use>` elements have a significant impact on the rendering performance. Negligible/not noticeable when using only a few instances. In your case you probably need to animate quite a lot of elements – you'll see a difference in in a Dev tools/ lighthouse benchmark test. So my solution is rather a fair compromise if you prefer svg.